# Removal of println containing next() causes an infinite loop?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

I must be missing something obvious about how the various Scanner methods work but this really doesn't make any sense:

this code causes an infinite loop:

```
Scanner valueScan = new Scanner(line);
valueScan.useDelimiter(",");
while(valueScan.hasNext())
{
count++;
}
```

while this code is valid:

```
Scanner valueScan = new Scanner(line);
valueScan.useDelimiter(",");
while(valueScan.hasNext())
{
System.out.println("value token: " + valueScan.next());
cellCount++;
}
```

This is from Oracle's documentation I am not sure if it applies or what it means: "This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true. " (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `hasNext` doesn't remove anything from the `Scanner`, so in your first case, you never change its state, hence the infinite loop.  `next` extracts input, and hence changes the state of the `Scanner`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense but I just don't understand why this isn't explicitly mentioned in the method detail ? Maybe it's just me but when I read "Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner" it sounds like an accessor-like method and not something that is doing any updates.

Comment: @user1086516: Ah ok.  `hasNext`/`next` is a standard Java idiom for iterators.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `valueScan.next()` in your second example is what makes the scanner move forward. `hasNext()` only checks that there is a next item in your scanner but doesn't do anything else, hence the infinte loop if there is at least one item.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `next()` the `Scanner` wont iterate.

Answer (score 0):

`hasnext` only tells you if next element is present and `next` goes to that element.

so in your first loop, it stays at the first element and keeps telling you that second element is present and does nothing more.